# Wget progress in script

Tags: docker, wget

I have a `Dockerfile` which clones a repo and runs a shell script that exists inside that repo ...

Example

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/DaehwanKimLab/hisat-genotype.git /hisatgenotype
WORKDIR /hisatgenotype
RUN ["/bin/bash", "setup.sh", "-r"]
```

The problem I have is that the script uses `wget` but because `docker` executes it as non-tty, the resulting progress is displayed in `dot` mode.

This exceeds the buffer for the log not allowing me to see everything that's happening during the `docker build`.

I'd prefer to have the `wget` progress be displayed as a bar, but how can I pass this to the script?

Comment: Does `> /dev/null` work?

Comment: wouldn't `> /dev/null` produce no output at all for `setup.sh`?  I just want to kill the massive output from the `wget` lines in the script.

Comment: Add it only to the `wget` line in the script.

Comment: The script isn't mine.  It's cloned from the repo above.  The below suggest modifying the lines to change the output type.  That seems to make more sense than just throwing the output into `null`

Answer (score 3):

> non-tty(...)I'd prefer to have the `wget` progress be displayed as a bar

According to [`wget`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) man page

> When the output is not a TTY, the progress bar always falls back to
> "dot", even if `--progress=bar` was passed to Wget during invocation.
> This behaviour can be overridden and the "bar" output forced by using
> the "force" parameter as `--progress=bar:force`.

So you should add `--progress=bar:force` to your `wget` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SED to replace all your wget to use progress bar and quiet mode.

```
sed -i "/wget ftp:/ s/$/ -q --show-progress/" setup.sh
```

Also, add the `-i` to apply the change in the file.

Comment: I'm tying to add the `sed` line to the `Dockerfile` to modify the cloned `setup.sh` but it doesn't seem to have an effect.  Using `RUN sed '/^wget/ s/$/ -q --show-progress /g ' setup.sh`

Comment: It is because you `setup.sh` has an indentation in the file before wget. So you need to replace the search pattern. Check the updated answer.